# Why did Morla's eyes have a paralyzing effect on Atreyu?

Tags: german-language, michael-ende, the-neverending-story

The Swamp of Sadness apparently had no effect on Atreyu, which Artax thought was likely due to him wearing the Amulet. That being the case, he's later obliged to consciously resist the paralyzing effect of Morla's eyes. Why did Morla's eyes have an effect when the Swamp didn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amulet offered resistance against the ambient, passive sadness of the swamp, but Morla’s paralyzing gaze was an additional effect directly focused on Atreyu. Like yeah, your umbrella can protect you from the rain and wind — but not a firehose.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Can you expand your answer to explain your reasoning? Which passages from *The Neverending Story* led you to your conclusion?

Comment: That's a good point - that makes sense to me.